# Android Studio release build does not output aar

Tags: android, android-studio, release, aar

I have create a very simple 'Android Library' module with only one class which builds fine in debug releasing build/output/library-debug.aar

But, when I switch to release, even though it says build successful, the aar is not there.

The Android Studio project only has this library module.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Add your build.gradle.

Comment: @AgustinSivoplás I created the module from inside Android Studio, so I do have the build.gradle of the module.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

To get the aar, you can do the following

1) “View/Tool Windows/Gradle”, to open the gradle window

2) From gradle window, run assembly Gradle task by double-click on My_Plugin_Android/:My_Plugin/Tasks/build/assemble

Then the release and debug aars are outputed.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! This answer needs to be higher in Google search results.

I had a similar issue with Android Studio 3.0, where an app converted to a library would not output any .aar. Build > Build APK(s) would do *nothing*, not even output any form of error message ; and command line gradlew (4.2.1 on MacOS High Sierra) would give me "env: bash\r: No such file or directory"... probably a windows-to-mac issue...

Comment: Still no aar directory in outputs directory :(

Comment: OK it works! The aar file is under module folder, not app folder. My bad :P

Comment: Absolutely classic beginner's problem solved, thank you!

Comment: 'assemble' produced nothing in my studio, but 'bundle' target did the production

Comment: in my case it was "assembleRelease" the only way to output the aars

Answer (score 24):

Here are the steps:

```
Step1: In Android studio open 'gradle' window.
Step2: Select your library from the gradles projects
Step3: Click on Tasks => build => assemble
```

The aar file will be generated in 'build/outputs' folder in finder window.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the following line is there in your `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

- Open gradle window in android studio (Look at right top corner)
- Double click on Library => Tasks => build => assemble

Answer (score 1):

From Gradle > select your project > Tasks > Build > build dependents

As shown in below image :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Click `build` -> `selcet build Variant` menu
2. Select `release` in `Bulid Variants` panel
3. Click `build` -> `Rebuild project` menu
4. Open folder: `<project_name>/<module_name>/build/outputs/aar`

You can find release aar.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your project as an `Android library`.
In `build.gradle` file:  `plugin: 'com.android.library'`
You can see the output in: `build/outputs/aar/[your module]`.

Read [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format) article about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle:MyModule

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}
```

Remove android -> defaultConfig -> applicationId if it was attached.

Sync and build from Gradle task menu